# Project Open - How to implement notification to custom workflow in Project Open?

Tags: xml

We have created a custom workflow for new absence type permission in Project Open V3.5,but notifications are not working for the workflow.Please let me know what is the procedure to implement workflow to the newly created workflow.
Thanks,
Anu